# segmentation fault(core dumped) for >>> from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am currently working in a python project, using opencv in Anaconda.
I did some updates to my NumPy library and after that, the below import command gives me a segmentation fault (core dumped):

```
>>> from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity
```

Now what should I do?

Comment: Go back to the old version of numpy? How did you update numpy?

Comment: i dont know wot was the problem. i uninstalled anaconda and installed it again.now it worked :)